# How to open a webpage in a new tab?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Presumably Avant browser has easier interface than any other browser that its icon has a small arrow to open a webpage ( a cool feature) in new tab-- I am particularly referring to its Favorite Bar. Downside is it hangs out frequently.

I am currently using IE11 browser but when I want to open a webpage on Favorite Bar, I have to right-click it to open in a new tab.

Could anyone know a keyboard shortcut to open it in new tab?

My PC is Win 7.

Answer (score 2):

I know two *shortcuts* that work on several browsers out there:

- Keep <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed, and then <kbd>Left Click</kbd> on the desired button under the *Favorites* bar.
- <kbd>Middle Click</kbd> the desired button under the *Favorites* bar.

Answer (score 1):

Middle mouse click or ctrl+click or ctrl+enter once the link is highlighted.